# I would like to replace a rect with an image in sdl

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to make the paddle an actual image instead of a rect in this breakout clone. I would also like to change the bricks into images. I just don't know how to use images like rects and am trying to figure it out.

```
//The headers
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

//For cap fps
#define fps 60

//The screen attributes
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1008;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

//coordinates of ball
const int BALL_X = 500;
const int BALL_Y = 600;

//Declaring for color
Uint32 white;

//The surfaces
SDL_Surface *mainScreen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *difficultyScreen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *result = NULL;
SDL_Surface *result2 = NULL;

//The event structure
SDL_Event event;

//Rects
SDL_Rect Paddle;
SDL_Rect Ball;
SDL_Rect Block1;
SDL_Rect Block2;
SDL_Rect Block3;
SDL_Rect Block4;
SDL_Rect Block5;
SDL_Rect Block6;
SDL_Rect Block7;
SDL_Rect Block8;
SDL_Rect Block9;
SDL_Rect Block10;
SDL_Rect Block11;
SDL_Rect Block12;
SDL_Rect Block13;
SDL_Rect Block14;
SDL_Rect Block15;
SDL_Rect Block16;
SDL_Rect Block17;
SDL_Rect Block18;
SDL_Rect Block19;
SDL_Rect Block20;
SDL_Rect Block21;
SDL_Rect Block22;
SDL_Rect Block23;
SDL_Rect Block24;
SDL_Rect Block25;
SDL_Rect Block26;

int xVel, yVel;

bool PointInRect(int x, int y, SDL_Rect rec)
{
    if (x > rec.x && y > rec.y && x < rec.x + rec.w && y < rec.y + rec.h)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool CheckCollision(SDL_Rect r1, SDL_Rect r2)
{
    if (PointInRect(r1.x, r1.y, r2) == true ||
        PointInRect(r1.x + r1.w, r1.y, r2) == true ||
        PointInRect(r1.x, r1.y + r1.h, r2) == true ||
        PointInRect(r1.x + r1.w, r1.y + r1.h, r2) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*bool ChackCollision(SDL_Rect r3, SDL_Rect r4)
{
    if (PointInRect(r3.x, r3.y, r4) == true ||
         PointInRect(r3.x + r3.w, r3.y, r4) == true)
    {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}*/

void ResetBall()
{
    Ball.x = BALL_X;
    Ball.y = BALL_Y;
    xVel = 3;
    yVel = 3;
}

void LoadGame()
{
    Paddle.x = 425;
    Paddle.y = 650;
    Paddle.h = 20;
    Paddle.w = 150;

    Ball.x = BALL_X;
    Ball.y = BALL_Y;
    Ball.h = 15;
    Ball.w = 15;

    Block1.x = 58;
    Block1.y = 28;
    Block1.h = 15;
    Block1.w = 100;

    Block2.x = 216;
    Block2.y = 28;
    Block2.h = 15;
    Block2.w = 100;

    Block3.x = 374;
    Block3.y = 28;
    Block3.h = 15;
    Block3.w = 100;

    Block4.x = 533;
    Block4.y = 28;
    Block4.h = 15;
    Block4.w = 100;

    Block5.x = 691;
    Block5.y = 28;
    Block5.h = 15;
    Block5.w = 100;

    Block6.x = 849;
    Block6.y = 28;
    Block6.h = 15;
    Block6.w = 100;

    Block7.x = 84;
    Block7.y = 71;
    Block7.h = 15;
    Block7.w = 100;

    Block8.x = 269;
    Block8.y = 71;
    Block8.h = 15;
    Block8.w = 100;

    Block9.x = 453;
    Block9.y = 71;
    Block9.h = 15;
    Block9.w = 100;

    Block10.x = 638;
    Block10.y = 71;
    Block10.h = 15;
    Block10.w = 100;

    Block11.x = 822;
    Block11.y = 71;
    Block11.h = 15;
    Block11.w = 100;

    Block12.x = 23;
    Block12.y = 114;
    Block12.h = 15;
    Block12.w = 100;

    Block13.x = 146;
    Block13.y = 114;
    Block13.h = 15;
    Block13.w = 100;

    Block14.x = 269;
    Block14.y = 114;
    Block14.h = 15;
    Block14.w = 100;

    Block15.x = 392;
    Block15.y = 114;
    Block15.h = 15;
    Block15.w = 100;

    Block16.x = 516;
    Block16.y = 114;
    Block16.h = 15;
    Block16.w = 100;

    Block17.x = 639;
    Block17.y = 114;
    Block17.h = 15;
    Block17.w = 100;

    Block18.x = 762;
    Block18.y = 114;
    Block18.h = 15;
    Block18.w = 100;

    Block19.x = 885;
    Block19.y = 114;
    Block19.h = 15;
    Block19.w = 100;

    Block20.x = 88;
    Block20.y = 157;
    Block20.h = 15;
    Block20.w = 100;

    Block21.x = 820;
    Block21.y = 157;
    Block21.h = 15;
    Block21.w = 100;

    Block22.x = 138;
    Block22.y = 200;
    Block22.h = 15;
    Block22.w = 100;

    Block23.x = 296;
    Block23.y = 200;
    Block23.h = 15;
    Block23.w = 100;

    Block24.x = 454;
    Block24.y = 200;
    Block24.h = 15;
    Block24.w = 100;

    Block25.x = 612;
    Block25.y = 200;
    Block25.h = 15;
    Block25.w = 100;

    Block26.x = 770;
    Block26.y = 200;
    Block26.h = 15;
    Block26.w = 100;

    white = SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255);

    srand(time(NULL));

    ResetBall();
}
void Logic()
{
    SDL_Event occur;
    SDL_PollEvent(&occur);
    Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    if (keystates[SDLK_LEFT])
    {
        Paddle.x -= 8;
    }
    if (keystates[SDLK_RIGHT])
    {
        Paddle.x += 8;
    }
    if (Paddle.x < 1)
    {
        Paddle.x = 1;
    }
    if (Paddle.x + Paddle.w > 1007)
    {
        Paddle.x = 1007 - Paddle.w;
    }

    //For ball movement
    Ball.x += xVel;
    Ball.y += yVel;

    //Change the direction of the ball if ball hits the walls
    if (Ball.y < 1)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
    }
    if (Ball.x < 1)
    {
        xVel = -xVel;
    }
    if (Ball.x + Ball.w > 1007)
    {
        xVel = -xVel;
    }


    //Change the direction of the ball if ball hits the paddle
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Paddle) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
    }

    //Change the direction of the ball if ball hits the blocks
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block1) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block1.x = -200;
        Block1.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block2) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block2.x = -200;
        Block2.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block3) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block3.x = -200;
        Block3.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block4) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block4.x = -200;
        Block4.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block5) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block5.x = -200;
        Block5.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block6) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block6.x = -200;
        Block6.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block7) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block7.x = -200;
        Block7.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block8) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block8.x = -200;
        Block8.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block9) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block9.x = -200;
        Block9.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block10) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block10.x = -200;
        Block10.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block11) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block11.x = -200;
        Block11.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block12) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block12.x = -200;
        Block12.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block13) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block13.x = -200;
        Block13.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block14) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block14.x = -200;
        Block14.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block15) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block15.x = -200;
        Block15.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block16) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block16.x = -200;
        Block16.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block17) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block17.x = -200;
        Block17.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block18) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block18.x = -200;
        Block18.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block19) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block19.x = -200;
        Block19.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block20) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block20.x = -200;
        Block20.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block21) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block21.x = -200;
        Block21.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block22) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block22.x = -200;
        Block22.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block23) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block23.x = -200;
        Block23.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block24) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block24.x = -200;
        Block24.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block25) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block25.x = -200;
        Block25.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block26) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block26.x = -200;
        Block26.y = -200;
    }


//Function to load image
SDL_Surface *load_Image( std::string filename )
{
    //Temporary storage for the image that's loaded
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;

    //The optimized image that will be used
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;
    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(filename.c_str());

    //If nothing went wrong in loading the image
    if(loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        //Create an optimized image
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);

        //Free the old surface
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    }
    //Return the optimized image
    return optimizedImage;
}
//Function to apply picture to screen
void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL)
{
    //Holds offsets
    SDL_Rect offset;

    //Get offsets
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    //Blit
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, destination, &offset);
}
//Function to start SDL
bool init()
{
    //Initialize all SDL subsystems
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    //set up the screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE );

    //If there was an error in setting up the screen
    if( screen == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Name the window
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Block Breaker", NULL );

    //If everything initialized fine
    return true;
}
//Function to load files
bool load_files()
{
    //Load the image
    mainScreen = load_Image( "Menu.bmp" );
    difficultyScreen = load_Image( "Speed Menu.bmp" );
    result = load_Image( "Results.bmp" );
    result2 = load_Image( "Results2.bmp" );

    return true;
}
//function to stop SDL
void clean_up()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(mainScreen);
    SDL_FreeSurface(difficultyScreen);
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    SDL_FreeSurface(result);
    SDL_FreeSurface(result2);

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
}
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

    //Variables
    bool running = true;
    bool menu = true;
    bool difficulty = false;
    bool mediumGame = false;
    bool grayGameScreen = false;
    bool hardGame = false;
    bool quit = false;
    bool Result = false;
    bool Result2 = false;

    //Initialize
    if ( init() == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //Quit function
    if (quit == true)
    {
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    //Load the files
    if ( load_files() == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //Load Game
    LoadGame();

    Uint32 starting_tick;
    //while the user hasn't quit
    while (quit == false)
    {
        starting_tick = SDL_GetTicks();
        //Menu screen
        if (menu==true)
        {
            //Apply screen
            apply_surface(0,0,mainScreen,screen);

            //Loop to handle input by user
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type==SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
                {
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    {
                        int x = event.button.x;
                        int y = event.button.y;
                        //Button for difficulty screen
                        if ((x>370)&&(x<660)&&(y>265)&&(y<370))
                        {
                            menu = false;
                            difficulty = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                        if ((x>374)&&(x<660)&&(y>390)&&(y<500))
                        {
                            menu = false;
                            quit = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                    }
                SDL_Flip(screen);
                }
                else if (event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
            SDL_Flip(screen);
        }

        //Difficulty screen
        else if (difficulty==true)
        {
            //Apply surface
            apply_surface(0,0,difficultyScreen,screen);
            SDL_Flip(screen);

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type==SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
                {
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    {
                        int x = event.button.x;
                        int y = event.button.y;
                        //Button for medium game screen
                        if ((x>360)&&(x<660)&&(y>370)&&(y<465))
                        {
                            difficulty = false;
                            mediumGame = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                        //Button for hard game screen
                        if ((x>420)&&(x<610)&&(y>490)&&(y<575))
                        {
                            difficulty = false;
                            hardGame = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                    }
                SDL_Flip(screen);
                }
                else if (event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //Medium game screen
        else if (mediumGame == true)
        {
            //Fill color
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0x68, 0x68, 0x68 ));

            //Logic for the game
            Logic();

            //Place Paddle
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Paddle, white);

            //Place Ball
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Ball, white);

            //Place Blocks
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block1, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block2, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block3, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block4, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block5, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block6, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block7, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block8, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block9, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block10, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block11, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block12, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block13, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block14, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block15, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block16, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block17, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block18, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block19, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block20, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block21, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block22, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block23, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block24, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block25, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block26, white);

            //Loser
            if (Ball.y + Ball.h > 719)
            {
                mediumGame = false;
                Result2 = true;
                SDL_Flip(screen);
            }

            //Winner
            if (Block1.x != 58 &&
                Block2.x != 216 &&
                Block3.x != 374 &&
                Block4.x != 533 &&
                Block5.x != 691 &&
                Block6.x != 849 &&
                Block7.x != 84 &&
                Block8.x != 269 &&
                Block9.x != 453 &&
                Block10.x != 638 &&
                Block11.x != 822 &&
                Block12.x != 23 &&
                Block13.x != 146 &&
                Block14.x != 269 &&
                Block15.x != 392 &&
                Block16.x != 516 &&
                Block17.x != 639 &&
                Block18.x != 762 &&
                Block19.x != 885 &&
                Block20.x != 88 &&
                Block21.x != 820 &&
                Block22.x != 138 &&
                Block23.x != 296 &&
                Block24.x != 454 &&
                Block25.x != 612 &&
                Block26.x != 770)
            {
                hardGame = false;
                Result = true;
                SDL_Flip(screen);
            }

            //Flip screen
            SDL_Flip(screen);
        }

        //Hard game screen
        else if (hardGame == true)
        {
            //Fill color
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0x68, 0x68, 0x68 ));

            //Logic for the game
            Logic();

            //Place Paddle
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Paddle, white);

            //Place Ball
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Ball, white);

            //Place Blocks
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block1, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block2, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block3, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block4, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block5, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block6, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block7, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block8, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block9, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block10, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block11, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block12, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block13, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block14, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block15, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block16, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block17, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block18, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block19, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block20, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block21, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block22, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block23, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block24, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block25, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block26, white);

            //Loser
            if (Ball.y + Ball.h > 720)
            {
                hardGame = false;
                Result2 = true;
                SDL_Flip(screen);
            }

            //Winner
            if (Block1.x != 58 &&
                Block2.x != 216 &&
                Block3.x != 374 &&
                Block4.x != 533 &&
                Block5.x != 691 &&
                Block6.x != 849 &&
                Block7.x != 84 &&
                Block8.x != 269 &&
                Block9.x != 453 &&
                Block10.x != 638 &&
                Block11.x != 822 &&
                Block12.x != 23 &&
                Block13.x != 146 &&
                Block14.x != 269 &&
                Block15.x != 392 &&
                Block16.x != 516 &&
                Block17.x != 639 &&
                Block18.x != 762 &&
                Block19.x != 885 &&
                Block20.x != 88 &&
                Block21.x != 820 &&
                Block22.x != 138 &&
                Block23.x != 296 &&
                Block24.x != 454 &&
                Block25.x != 612 &&
                Block26.x != 770)
            {
                hardGame = false;
                Result = true;
                SDL_Flip(screen);
            }

            //Flip screen
            SDL_Flip(screen);
        }

        //Win menu
        else if (Result == true)
        {
            apply_surface(0,0,result,screen);
            LoadGame();
            SDL_Flip(screen);

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type==SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
                {
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    {
                        int x = event.button.x;
                        int y = event.button.y;

                        //Button for medium game screen
                        if ((x>360)&&(x<660)&&(y>370)&&(y<465))
                        {
                            Result = false;
                            difficulty = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }

                        //Button for hard game screen
                        if ((x>420)&&(x<610)&&(y>490)&&(y<575))
                        {
                            Result = false;
                            quit = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                    }
                    SDL_Flip(screen);
                }
                else if (event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //Lose menu
        else if (Result2 == true)
        {
            apply_surface(0,0,result2,screen);
            LoadGame();
            SDL_Flip(screen);

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type==SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
                {
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    {
                        int x = event.button.x;
                        int y = event.button.y;

                        //Button for medium game screen
                        if ((x>360)&&(x<660)&&(y>370)&&(y<465))
                        {
                            Result = false;
                            difficulty = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }

                        //Button for hard game screen
                        if ((x>420)&&(x<610)&&(y>490)&&(y<575))
                        {
                            Result = false;
                            quit = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                    }
                    SDL_Flip(screen);
                }
                else if (event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //Cap fps
        if (( 1000/fps) > SDL_GetTicks() - starting_tick)
        {
            SDL_Delay( 1000/fps - ( SDL_GetTicks() - starting_tick ));
        }
    }

    //Clean up
    clean_up();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code, are you sure they are all relevant to your question? Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You haven't asked a question. If the question is 'how can you draw image on screen', your code already have an answer - with `SDL_BlitSurface`.

Comment: What's the problem that you're having?  What results are you getting?  What have you tried (besides the code you've pasted)?  Have you checked any error codes/messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code for displaying an image:

Loading the image:

```
SDL_Rect image_hitbox;
SDL_Texture* image = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, filelocation.c_str());
```

Now, if you want the image to be displayed at a certain size, without consideration of the size of the image itself, just set it like normal:

```
image_hitbox.x = locationX;
image_hitbox.y = locationY;
image_hitbox.w = width;
image_hitbox.h = height;
```

If you would like width and height to depend on the picture itself, you can do this:

```
SDL_QueryTexture(image, nullptr, nullptr, &image_hitbox.w, &image_hitbox.h);
```

which will get the textures width and height for you.

Then, to simply render the image, you do this:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, image, nullptr, &image_hitbox);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

which will render the image (and scale it to the set width and height) at the coordinates in image_hitbox.

I'm not 100% sure this is exactly what you asked for, especially since you seem to be rendering surfaces instead of textures, but I can recommend using textures instead, as they use your GPU instead of your CPU.